# SQL Server date formatting issue

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2008 database with a transaction table. There is a field defined as NVARCHAR(16).  The data stored is date and time formatted like this:
 2016100708593100

I need to write a query that looks at that field and pulls data between two dates

```
select ... from...where convert(varchar,
      convert(datetime,left(a.xact_dati,8)),101) 
      between '9/29/2016' and '10/05/2016'
```

I have tried other converts but nothing returns any data.  If I use >=getdate()-1
I get data so I should be seeing something returned.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you storing timestamps as `NVARCHAR`? That's a really bad decision

Comment: try convert format 112 instead of 101

Comment: It is a vendor database so I have no say in how the data is stored.  I tried 112 it also returns no data.

Comment: The 10/07/2016 was just the max date in the table.

Comment: your dates expressed as 'between '9/29/2016' and '10/05/2016' ' ca nbe problematic, use the ISO 'YYYMMDD' format, e.g '20161005'

Comment: Btw: Checking date ranges with `BEWTEEN` is a [Aaron Bertrand: bad habit to kick](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries). 'BETWEEN' is inclusive and will take the very first second of the final day, but you will miss all days with a time portion of this day.

Comment: Btw2: One should also avoid to rely on culture specific date/time formats. Your `between '9/29/2016' and '10/05/2016'` might work on your system, might pass all tests, but still might break on a customer's system...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace WHERE Clause with

```
... WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(a.xact_dati,8)) BETWEEN '9/29/2016' AND '10/05/2016'
```

Comment: This is not sargable and relying on culture specific formats... I'd not advise this...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming YMD order just

```
where cast(left('2016100708593100', 8) as date) between '20160929' and '20161005'
```

Note this clause is not satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're trying to do a date comparison with varchar data.

You go half way to converting the initial value to datetime but then back to varchar.

You could rely on Sql to implicitly convert the between parameters to datetime.

```
select 'matched',convert(datetime,left('2016100708593100',8),112)
where convert(datetime,left('2016100708593100',8),112) between '2016/09/29' and '2016/10/10'
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the date part of the string and `CAST` it as `DATE` and then compare it with the proper date format.

```
select ... from... 
where cast(left('2016100708593100', 8) as date)  between '2016-09-29' and '2016-10-10'
```

Answer (score 0):

a very straight and fast approach could be to keep this in `BIGINT`

Something like this:

```
  cast(left(a.xact_dati,8) as bigint) between 20160929 and 20161005
```

But anyway this will not be sargable and therefore cannot use an index.

You might even stick to varchar, as the YYYYMMDD format is safe with alphanumerical sorting. Cutting a string with `LEFT` is sargable (AFAIK):

```
  left(a.xact_dati,8) between '20160929' and '20161005'
```